# angularjs: Change checkbox to image on selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want to implement a functionality in which, whenever a user checks a checkbox, it will get replace with a check image. For example:

[image]

So if I select first option it should get replace with a check image. 
[image]

I am able to replace the checkbox with image, but this new element looses the ng-click event.

Below is the code:

```
  currentController.changeChoice = function ($event, value) {

    if ($event.target.checked) {
        currentController.selectedOptions.push(value);
        $($event.target).replaceWith('<div ng-click="stock.changeChoice($event,option);"><img src="../images/check.png"  alt="remove" ng-checked="stock.selectedOptions.indexOf(option) > -1" /> </div>');
    }
    else {
        var index = currentController.selectedOptions.indexOf(value)
        currentController.selectedOptions.splice(index, 1);
    }
};
```

below is the html generated for the new element (image)

```
<div ng-click="stock.changeChoice($event,option);"><img src="../images/check.png" alt="remove" ng-checked="stock.selectedOptions.indexOf(option) > -1"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If angular way you have to use ng-show(or ng-if) for hide or show image and checkbox depends of the state. They both have to use same on-click callback. Here is the basic idea on pseudocode

```
<input ng-show="!is_checked" ng-click="callback()" ... />
<img  ng-show="is_checked" ng-click="callback()" ... />
```

Comment: If you put the check image in front of the input field as a layered <div> that is shown when you click the checkbox it would look nice if the check image has transparency. Then you simply have to show/hide the check image on click, and the checkbox itself will be a static element. (You might have to render the checkbox as an image or do some ninja trick in order not to change it's state when clicking it.)